# Getting "cut off" HTML values from database then output it on the site

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I'm storing an HTML values in my database then I output it on my site.
There was an HTML value that has a "cut off" HTML (*I don't have control on the HTML, since I'm getting it on a different website*" ), meaning to say, it looks like this

```
<a href="http://site.com
```

When I output this on my site I'm having a problem because below those "cut off" HTML, other HTML will be affected, so it looks like this (example)

```
<a href="http://site.com  <input type="button" value="test" />
```

My question here is that how would I know if an HTML is being cut off, then if it has been cut off, I want to close it by simple closing it with `" or />`

Comment: Can you post your code? exactly whats happening. it totally confusing while reading your post

Comment: on what part were you exactly confused? feels like I explained it well. :)

Comment: What you have done and what you want to acheive

Comment: I want to check if an html has not been closed, just like on my example <pre><a href="http://site.com </pre>, it has no " and />, so from there, I want to add a " and /> at the end of the HTML that hasn't been closed.

Comment: What if the broken HTML was `<a href="http://sit`? You can't possibly generate a fix for every instance of broken HTML. There's a million ways something like that can break. You'd be better off removing the broken HTML completely.

Comment: Actually, that's the reason why i'm asking it in stackoverflow, because maybe you guys have an idea on how to dynamically detect a broken html then fixed it.
Okay, I better removed the broken HTML, I hope you have a code for that and show it here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to see if it's cut off or not would be to look if the amount of <'s is the same as the amount of >'s. So like this:

```
<?php
list($len, $a, $b) = array(strlen($html), 0, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $char = $html[$i++]) {
    if ($char == '<')
        $a++;
    if ($char == '>')
        $b++;
}
$broken = true;
if ($a == $b)
    $broken = false;
```

Comment: Oh boy! Thank goodness there's someone who understood my question because feels like almost everyone didn't and there's even someone who gave me a vote down. 
You answer is a good head start for me.
Thanks! Greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you store them in the database? Are they cut off in database too? If yes, then make sure you store them in database through mysql_real_escape_string(), since it seems your HTML gets broken due to being inserted into database somehow.

Comment: The question is not about how to store them in database. It's about outputing the cutoff html values from the database, so yes, they too are cut off in database, just like <pre><a href="mysite</pre>  
See, there no " />.

Comment: If the problem were broken queries due to quotes, he would have known (the query would have..broke). Mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do with html, otherwise

Comment: Then your problem is not in the output or input to database, but where-ever you get the HTML from, in which case you have to validate far more than the broken tag. You need to fix that instead of output.

Comment: I have no control over the HTML that i'm getting since I'm getting it from a different site via some code that I created, since your saying about validation, do you have any idea how to validate it?

Comment: Then your problem is in that 'some code that I created'. You need to fix the code that gets that HTML.